# Trying to move file(s) from one directory to another by keyword

Tags: vb.net

I have a dropdown box that allows a user to move a file containing a certain keyword from one directory to another. For now, I am using my own documents folder until I can find a universal path for the documents folder. My first dropdown option is to delete, and my second is to move them. However, either one I choose deletes the file, and I was wondering if anyone could tell me why/how to fix it.

I have tried to use the move function on its own by commenting out the delete function and using the second option as its own statement and it still deletes, as far as I can tell.

```
Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

Dim filepath = IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
           txtPathBox.Text)

        Dim keyword As String = boxKeyword.Text

        If boxOption1.SelectedItem = "Delete" Then
            Dim files = From fl In IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath)
                        Where fl.Contains(keyword)
                        Select fl
            For Each fl In files
                IO.File.Delete(fl)
            Next

        ElseIf boxOption1.SelectedItem = "Archive" Then
            Dim files = From fl In IO.Directory.GetFiles(filepath)
                            Where fl.Contains(keyword)
                            Select fl
                For Each fl In files
                My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(fl, "C:\Users\Lee\Documents\Archived", True)
            Next
            End If





    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through the code and examined the state at each step?  If not, it's too early to be posting a question here. If so, you have omitted all the relevant information you discovered by doing so. If you don't know how to debug properly, now would be the time to learn.

Comment: I have mentioned that I tried running it without my first if statement to see if it would run the same.

Comment: The second parameter of [`FileSystem.MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.movefile?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_FileSystem_MoveFile_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) is the destination _file path_, not the destination _folder_. On another note, I suggest that you use [`File.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move) instead. The `My.Computer` object is only available in VB while `File.Move` is the framework standard.

Comment: *"I have mentioned that..."*. That's not really relevant to whether you have debugged it. More often than not, you can't fix issues simply by reading the code or looking at the application. You have to actually watch the code as it executes and examine the state of the application along the way. That's debugging and it requires setting breakpoints in your code and using the various tools the IDE provides, e.g. Watch and Immediate windows. If you haven't done that then you haven't debugged and if you haven't debugged then it's too soon to post here.